# Do I need to explain every word I use so that someone with no prior knowledge of the question can answer it?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, vote-to-close

Do I need to explain every word I use so that someone with no prior knowledge of the question can answer it?

e.g.

[Is every mistake or reactionary form of Marxism "substitutionalist"?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/41041/is-every-mistake-or-reactionary-form-of-marxism-substitutionalist?noredirect=1#comment101702_41041)

Comment: Could you explain how this question is different from http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/3251/2953? Thanks.

Comment: @Keelan good spot, sorry. if you're sure it's the same then delete it :)

Comment: No problem. I'll mark it as a duplicate then, but if there is something different, please edit it and we can reopen it.

Comment: @Keelan ok sure. i don't think it is different, can't see it